# For loop doesn't increment the counter 'i'

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, counter, increment

```
double n = 1.3243;
for (int i = 0; long(n*10) % 10 != 0; i++, n *= 10) {

}
```

I've written this code in order to understand whether a number has a decimal part or not.

At the end of the loop 'i' should be 4 but for some reason the counter doesn't increment.

Except for the fact that you may not like my solution, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Since floating-point numbers aren't exact, you'd be better off checking `if ((int)n - n) < epsilon)`...

Comment: In the code you pasted, there's no possible way to know what `i` is at the end of the loop. Please post your real code.

Comment: Be prepared for "seems like a compiler bug" comments...

Comment: @H2CO3 He's casting to long before doing modular arithmatic, which works fine. No floating-point comparison going on here.

Comment: @Joost I know that, I'm saying that `1.3243` may not be exactly representable, so the loop may not end where OP thinks it should...

Comment: Works for me (as long as I move the declaration of `i` outside the loop). Could you show a *complete*, *runnable* example that doesn't work for you, and state which compiler you're using.

Comment: @H2CO3 You're right, I'm sorry. On edge cases, i might be one higher or lower due to floating point rounding. In general it works, though, and it's as good as it gets when you've got no additional information about the float.

Comment: @Joost Of course, and you are right too in either case :) No worries.

Comment: When corrected (putting i outside for) 1.01 returns 0 decimals.

Comment: You're absolutely right, src! I'll revise it in my answer, below.

Comment: Yeah I know that "1.01" gives 0 decimal digits. I solved this bug using the "int(n) == n" statement suggested by Joost. Thank you guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end of your loop, the i-variable does no longer exist. You're declaring it inside the function scope. This results in not being able to access it outside the loop. If you do something like:

```
double n = 1.3243;
for (int i = 0; long(n*10) % 10 != 0; i++, n *= 10) {   
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```

GGC gives me a `loop.cpp:10: error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for new ISO ‘for’ scoping` error.

The following would fix that (notice how the for-loop does not need curly brackets if it's empty):

```
double n = 1.3243;
int i;
for (i = 0; long(n*10) % 10 != 0; i++, n *= 10);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Using GCC 4.2.1, this gives me the output of `4`

But the loop you presented has an inconvenient bug, when testing for decimal numbers. As [src remarked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776015/for-loop-doesnt-increment-the-counter-i/13776112#comment18941226_13776015) in his comment, a zero in the decimals cancels any decimals behind it. The loop simply breaks off as soon as it finds a zero value, but there could be more decimals following. Depending on the type of floats you're dealing with, this could be quite a problem.

**Do note:** The most common solution is the following comparison:

```
double n = 1.3243;
if (n == (int)n) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This fixes the error presented by src: `1.01` is said to have decimals, like it should. The loop solution (wrongly) returns `i=0` for this float.

The comparison `n == (int)n` returns true when your float does not have any decimal parts.

As [H2CO3 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776015/for-loop-doesnt-increment-the-counter-i/13776112#comment18941115_13776015), testing the decimals of a float-point number is not 100% definite, as floating point rounding might give you a slightly different answer than you're expecting. It works in the general case, though, so you'll have to see for yourself if it fits the problem you're solving.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joost, you solved my problem brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine. i =0 , n = 1.3243 .. i =1 , n = 13.243 .. i =2 , n = 123.43 .. i =3 , n = 1234.3 and then terminate if you declare "i" outside the for loop you will get it.